# Magento 2.1 configurable product times out

Tags: magento2, database, configurable-product, server-setup

**Background**
I do not think this is a bug but a server issue. When I create a large configurable product like a mattress that has 6 images for each of the 6 size configurations Magento only gets through about 4 products total before I get sent to a 404 page instead of back to the product page in the admin dashboard.

Thinking this may be because a server timeout or database timeout I have set PHP max execution to unlimited and my database to 360 seconds. This did not help though.

NOTE: I never made it to 360 seconds by the way. I get sent to the 404 page before that.

**Question(s)**

1. Has anyone resolved an issue similar to this before? Is this a bug in magento or am I correct in thinking it is a timeout issue?
2. What server settings should I be changing/ testing besides the 2 I did already?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Not that I remember, this was almost 5 years ago. I think it was an an image issue. The server or Magento would fail silently if one of the product images was over the limit.